# Best approach for user status while building an API

Tags: database, api, database-design, api-design

Suppose I do have a users table in my application. I want to give that user status like active, inactive, blocked, approved, and verified. What should be the best approach for that?
Should I use multiple table columns like active = 1, inactive = 0, etc, or just a single column name 'status' and put that active, inactive, or block status as a value?

Answer (score 0):

From a normalization perspective, you should keep 1-to-1 relationships within the same table.

You can also have a middle table where you store all of the available status values and use a foreign key to that table for each user record to set the status.